# return multiple reader.cast<>

Tags: c#, return, repository, reader

All I want to do is return multiple reader.cast<> so that i can use 2 sqlcommands.

```
var first =reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(x => new LocationInfo()

                        {
                            Names = x.GetString(0),
                            Values = Math.Round(x.GetDouble(1), 2).ToString("#,##0.00"),
                            ValuesDouble = x.GetDouble(1)

                        }).ToList();
                    reader.NextResult();

var second=reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(x => new LocationInfo()

                    {
                        Names2 = x.GetString(0),
                            Values2 = Math.Round(x.GetDouble(1), 2).ToString("#,##0.00"),
                            ValuesDouble2 = x.GetDouble(1)

                    }).ToList();
```

All I want to do is return var first and var second. Please help :(

I'm using this Location.cs for parameters:

```
namespace MVCRealtime
{
public class LocationInfo
{
    public string Names { get; set; }
    public string Values { get; set; }
    public double ValuesDouble { get; set; }
    public string Names2 { get; set; }
    public string Values2 { get; set; }
    public double ValuesDouble2 { get; set; }


}
```

}

Comment: What about `out` parameters?

Comment: its currently public IEnumerable<LocationInfo> GetData(). What should it be?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class ReaderHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<TElem> GetData<TElem>(this IDataReader reader, Func<IDataRecord, TElem> buildObjectDelegat)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            yield return buildObjectDelegat(reader);
        }
    }
}
// ...
var result = reader.GetData(x => new LocationInfo()
        {
            Names = x.GetString(0),
            Values = Math.Round(x.GetDouble(1), 2).ToString("#,##0.00"),
            ValuesDouble = x.GetDouble(1)
        }).Take(2);
```

So you get 1st var in 1st element of the result and 2nd var in 2nd element.

Comment: but isn't that only 1 result? I dont understand please elaborate.Thank you

Comment: `result` contains collection of 2 LocationInfo elements, obtained from the first 2 records of `reader`